# Enabling dual-channel recording with twilio-python

Tags: python, twilio

I am trying to enable dual-channel recording when initiating a call via Twilio. I'm using [twilio-python](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-python). The recordings are successful, but the output still comes out with 1 channel.

```
client = TwilioClient('MyTwilioAccountSID', 'MyTwilioAuthToken')

def call(phone_number, extra_digits=''):
    return client.calls.create(
                        url='http://my_url.com/twiml',
                        from_='+16315559288',
                        to=phone_number,
                        send_digits=extra_digits,
                        record=True,
                        recording_channels=2
                    )
```

Is there a different way to enable dual-channel recording?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For dual channel recording, You need to pass only `"dual"`.

So in your case `recording_channels='dual'`.

See this documentation
[link](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/make-calls#optional-parameters)